# curl_errno 56 on localhost

Tags: php, curl

I'm having trouble with php curl on my localhost for days. It seems that I'm not reaching the CURLOPT_URL parameter. curl_error and curl_errno says, "Recv failure: Connection was reset". The url is supposed to return a processed value of the passed post data. I'm using windows 7 machine and running XAMPP 3.2.2
Appreciate your help guys. Thanks

Below is my code:

```
private function getCurl ($credentials = array(), $app_code = "")
{
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('Code' => $code,'type' => 'credentials');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://localhost/web/service.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic ' . 
base64_encode($credentials['user'] . ":" . $credentials['pass'])));
$curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
//return array(curl_error($ch),curl_errno($ch));
curl_close($ch);
return $curl_response;
}
```

Comment: Can you check what is logged in your webserver logs?

Comment: Hi Droy, here are my logs from XAMPP

Comment: @DROY If it might help, I tried setting the app on a different computer, and the curl worked just fine. Recent changes from my computer were python and pip installation for django.

Comment: Did it run it as admin on the second computer?

Comment: can you check what you see in the XAMP control panel? Sometimes it is also due to the port 80 which may be in use by applications such as Skype.

Comment: Didn't used admin in the second computer to make it run

Comment: Ports on control panel are on 80,443. Already checked netstat -a ano no port 80 in used.

Comment: did u find a solution @NealeBañagale ? I am still having trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Apache error logs: [Thu Apr 14 07:46:54.089533 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3372:tid 252] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

There could be a number of reasons why this is happening. I think you should use the XAMP Control Panel to view the specific errors.

1. Quite possible that another application such as Skype is using port 80. In this case you may want to check using `netstat -ano` and find who is using port 80. Close the Program which uses port 80 and try to start apache again.
2. It may be due to your rights. You will need to be administrator.
3. Disable Anti-virus (Try first to disable skype and running again, if it didn't work do this step)
4. Right click on xampp control panel and run as administrator
5. `server name` used in Apache (httpd.conf) must be the same as the server name in apache (httpd-ssl.conf) e.g. in Apache (httpd.conf)ServerName localhost:8080 then in apache (httpd-ssl.conf) should be like this ServerName www.example.com:8080
6. You can also try to change the Configuration of Apache.
   a) Select Apache (httpd.conf)
   b) searched for this line: Listen 80 
   c) changed for this: Listen 8081
   d) saved file

   Further...
   a) Select Apache (httpd-ssl.conf) 
   b) searched for this line: Listen 443 
   c) changed for this: Listen 444
   d) saved file